# why typescript code in visual studio 2022 dont have any color, and code style

Tags: typescript

I have a project angular with asp.net webapi.

why typescript code in visual studio 2022 dont have any color, and code style?

please see below image.  just plain text, no color.

[image]

Comment: The problem indicator on the top of the screen shows a hung extension; i can imagine that may well be related.

Comment: hi Raxi, even I disable that extension still not show up, why interest, my lapop used to be other employee's , I changed login name,  visual studio for new project, can show typescript intelligence ,color out, but this project can not,, I create another local account for my laptop, login this new account, first time login,  open project, typescript color show up, but never got chance to show again.  dont know what cause it,  I copy to other laptop, work fine, just this  laptop, maybe related ,when I change original login name, something in windows still keep old information

Comment: have exact same problem, did you manage to solve this?